# Why doesn't this switch case program take character input after the integer input?

Tags: c, switch-statement, character, calculator

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char operator;
    int a,b;    

    printf("Enter 1st operands: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);    

    printf("Enter 2nd operands: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

   //here after taking the input of integers the code skips to default without 
//taking the character input 

    printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *,/): ");
    scanf("%c", &operator);

    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("%d+ %d = %d",a, b, a + b);
            break;

        case '-':
            printf("%d- %d = %d",a, b, a - b);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Error! operator is not correct");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @xing: Please write answers in the answer section, where they can be more readily peer reviewed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? or give any descriptive links? I didn't properly understand the matter. tia

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%c", &operator);` actually reads the newline character that remains on the input stream.

The remedy - `scanf(" %c", &operator);` - note the space, is the idiomatic way of getting round this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? or give any descriptive links? I didn't properly understand the matter. tia

Comment: Get your favourite debugger out. Look at `operator` before the `switch` block. Bet you a quid it's 10, corresponding to what happens when you press your Return key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
scanf(" %c", &operator);
      ^^^^
```

Otherwise control characters will be stored in the object.

From the function description in the C Standard (7.21.6.2 The fscanf function)

> 5 A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the ﬁrst non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? or give any descriptive links? I didn't properly understand the matter. tia

Comment: @AlinoorRahman See my updated post.